# First books for ~1300-1400 ELO player

Tags: books

I decided to buy a few books to start learning chess more deeply. I have decided on a tactics book (chess tactics for champion), a strategy book (mastering chess strategy) and an endgame book (silman's complete endgame course). I also have Silman's reassess your chess book. My question is the following: Is there anything missing? Is the tactics book suited for someone 1400 or higher, I don't want something too basic. Is it useful to get an opening book as well? I thought I would just learn openings as I go or on Lichess, but I was wondering if you would add anything in there.

Comment: Hey. A few thoughts from me. Play through a bunch of games by strong players to learn different patterns. Play a bunch of online games on Lichess to improve gradually. Watch YouTube videos. Ignore openings. Focus on endgames and middlegames, in that order. Good luck on your journey to chess mastery.